# How do you add hooks to multiple vertices at once?

Tags: rigging

I have a path with a lot of vertices and it seems very unnecessarily tedious that I have to click on each individual one to add a hook to it. Surely there must be some quick command that adds a unique hook to each individual vertex if I select all at once.